# use 'Collections.frequency' to get a count of instances given one value

Tags: java, collections, frequency

To simplify what I'm doing, let's use the example from [learnfromexamples.com](http://learnfromexamples.com/how-to-find-the-occurrences-of-a-particular-element-in-an-arraylist-in-java/) that I modified a few bits.

```
package test;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


class Employee {
        private String empno;
        private String empName;

        public Employee(String empno, String empName ) {
            this.empno = empno;
            this.empName = empName;
        }

        public String getEmpno() {
            return empno;
        }

        public void setEmpno(String empno) {
            this.empno = empno;
        }

        public String getEmpName() {
            return empName;
        }

        public void setEmpName(String empName) {
            this.empName = empName;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Empno is "+ empno + " Empname is " + empName;
        }
        public Employee() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean flag = false;
            Employee employee = (Employee) arg0;
            if(null!= employee && employee.getEmpName().equalsIgnoreCase(empName) && employee.getEmpno().equalsIgnoreCase(empno)){
                flag = true;
            }
            return flag;
        }

    }


public class Test  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        empList.add(new Employee("001", "Shidhar"));
        empList.add(new Employee("002", "Pathy"));
        empList.add(new Employee("003", "Sahana"));
        empList.add(new Employee("003", "Sahana"));
        empList.add(new Employee("004", "Sahana"));
        empList.add(new Employee("003", "Sahana"));

        //Get the occurrence of "new Employee("003", "Sahana")" from empLists
        //int sahanaCount = Collections.frequency(empList, new Employee("003"));
        //System.out.println("Count of sahana is : " +sahanaCount);

        Set<Employee> uniqueId = new HashSet<Employee>(empList);
        for (Employee emId : uniqueId) {
            System.out.println("The emp with id "+emId.getEmpno()+" was repeated: "
                    + Collections.frequency(empList, emId.getEmpName()));
        }

    }
}
```

Is it possible to use `Collections.frequency` to find frequency given one variable e.g. `Collections.frequency(empList,"Sahana");` that yields 4.

Another alternative is I can use HashMap to keep the count but let's say I'm impressed with `Collections.frequency` and try to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's impossible given your implementation of `equals`. In Java-8 instead of `Collections.frequency` you can use Stream API instead:

```
empList.stream().map(Employee::getEmpName).filter(emId.getEmpName()::equals).count();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but let's say I remove the `equals` method. Is it possible?

Comment: @bensw, you can redefine the `equals` comparing by name only (ignoring empno). But this may cause problems in some other code, so I would not recommend this as a general solution.

Comment: I have tried that but unfortunately, it outputted all 0s which not quite like what I expected. In other words, it did not count anything at all. Do you know what could have gone wrong?

Comment: @bensw, in such case you should pass `emId` instead of `emId.getEmpName()` as `frequency` method second parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried both of your code. It gave me what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

`Sets` are not suitable to store an object multiple times. Sets remove duplicates from it. You need to have several changes in your code to make this work out

- Use `ArrayList` or any other list implementation instead of `HashSet`
- In your `equals()` method, the equality of the object is done comparing both `empno` and `empName`.so, you should use the same `empno` value while creating the `Employee` object when adding to the collection to pass the equality comparison. Otherwise, the equal() method need to be modified.

The code change would be "003" instead of "004"

```
empList.add(new Employee("003", "Sahana"));
empList.add(new Employee("003", "Sahana"));
empList.add(new Employee("003", "Sahana"));
empList.add(new Employee("003", "Sahana"));
```

and remove the below line

```
Set<Employee> uniqueId = new HashSet<Employee>(empList);
```

where `HashSet` takes the list as the argument. Now, Iterate the list directly

```
for (Employee employee : empList) {
            System.out.println("The emp with id "+employee.getEmpno()+" was repeated: "
                    + Collections.frequency(empList, employee);
        }
```

and finally pass the `employee` instance instead of passing `empName` of the `employee` instance. This should print the number of duplicate objects present in the list. This is what `Collections.frequency` method is intended for.

To get the count based on 'empName', you should go for a custom implementation like

```
private int getCount(String empName){
    int count = 0;
    for (Employee employee : empList) {
        if(employee.getEmpName() != null && employee.getEmpName().equals(empName)){
count++;
}
            }
return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object)) itself

> Returns the number of elements in the specified collection equal to
>   the specified object. More formally, returns the number of elements e
>   in the collection such that (o == null ? e == null : o.equals(e)).

So yes you could use `Collections.frequency`. But you got to be careful with equals method and override it according to your implementation, which will identify equal objects for the `Collections.frequency` method

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. If I remove it, will it work? I wasn't aware that having it would affect my code this much.